# I want to create a package check on vb, but my codes aren't working any suggestion?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, package

I can't think of any other way to make it work, any suggestions?
This are my codes:

Public Class frmPackageCheck

```
Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    If txtWeight.Text <= 27 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Accepted"
    ElseIf txtWeight.Text >= 27 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Rejected: Too heavy"
    End If
    If txtLength.Text <= 100 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Accepted"
    ElseIf txtLength.Text >= 100 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Rejected: Too large"
    End If
    If lblWidth.Text <= 100 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Accepted"
    ElseIf txtWidth.Text >= 100 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Rejected: Too large"
    End If
    If txtHeight.Text <= 100 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Accepted"
    ElseIf txtHeight.Text >= 100 Then
        Me.lblAnswer.Text = "Rejected: Too large"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you'll see where you're going wrong.

Comment: You should explain what "my codes aren't working" mean... like this we can only guess what the problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is likely that `Me.lblAnswer.Text` keeps getting changed. For example, if the weight is 50, the answer text will be set to "Rejected: Too heavy", but in the next if-block it will get replaced (either by "Accepted" or "Rejected: Too large").  You should continue checking more values **only if** the state is 'accepted'. Once a rejection reason is found, you should report it.

Alternately you can build a more complicated answer text that is either a combination of all rejection reasons, or 'accepted'. This would be slightly more complicated to program but would find all problems in one pass.